# Java Huffman tree code "Decode" method not working

Tags: java, tree, huffman-code

I've been looking at this method for a while now, and I'm quite sure that this is a simple solution. I can't, for the life of me, figure out why my code returns `strin` whenever I pass a boolean array of `[false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, false, true, false, true, false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true, true]`. For some reason, the 'g' never makes it onto the string, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
public String decodeIter(boolean[] coding)
{
    String str = "";
    Node current = root;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < coding.length)
    {
        if(current != null)
        {
            if(current.left == null && current.right == null)
            {
                LeafNode leaf = (LeafNode) current;
                str += leaf.data;
                current = root;
            } else {
                if(coding[i] == true)
                {
                    current = current.right;
                    i++;
                } else {
                    current = current.left;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `str += leaf.data;` is the only time you add to str. Perhaps `leaf.data` is always either true or false?

Comment: @KnowNoTrend leaf.data is a character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is going to be that when you read the last entry in coding and it directs you to your character, you immediately i++, which will make the while condition on your loop false, and so the last str+= never gets called because its condition is never tested. There may be a cleaner remedy, but one approach would be to insert the following right before `return str`.

```
if(current!= null && current.left == null && current.right == null)//short circuit prevents dereferencing null pointer
{
    LeafNode leaf = (LeafNode) current;
    str += leaf.data;
    //no need to set current = root, we are leaving anyway
}
```

That should grab the last character for you.